# postgres default user deleting

Tags: database, postgresql

Greeting,
When I install postgres it created default user with username/password = postgres. Lets say I want to deploy to use the database in production. I cant leave the default user like that ,because everyone would be able to log in to my database(people know about this default user).Of course I can restrict the ip from server,but I think its not a good idea.

What should I do. Should I **DELETE DEFAULT USER**? Should I leave default user,but **CHANGE THE PASSWORD**?

Comment: Never delete the superuser (=postgres). If you want to make the installation secure, disallow logins from any other computer for that user (through pg_hba.conf)

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for quick reply. I see your point. Would it also be better if I change the default password for extra security?

Comment: Yes, change the password.  People screw up their pg_hba.conf all the time, changing the password is much more robust.

Comment: thanks @jjanes for reply. I agree with you completely. I'll definetely change the default password for extra security.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default password" for Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name when you install postgres it comes with default username postgres and password postgres. This is what I mean in default password

Comment: @sparrow_21: no it does not. On Linux, the postgres user has no password, and `pg_hba.conf` is configured to only allow local logins from the Linux user `postgres` (that's why all tutorials use `sudo postgres ...` to do anything as the superuser . On Windows you are asked to enter a password.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see. I used docker to start postgres and I specified password there. Thanks for help.

Comment: Then your docker image defined a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good options are:

- Change or clear the password.
- Disable logins as `postgres`:

  ```
  ALTER ROLE postgres NOLOGIN;
  ```

  That second option requires that you either have another superuser or that there is a role that can become `postgres` with `SET ROLE`:

  ```
  CREATE ROLE admin LOGIN NOINHERIT IN GROUP postgres;
  ```

Comment: thanks both a_horse_with_no_name and Laurenz for help.